# Symfony Translations domain not loaded

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization

I have a problem loading my translations. 
Right now i have 2 translation domains:
`messages` and `LokiTuoResultBundle.forms` both are in the `/src/%BUNDLE&/Resources/translations` folder. My translation `messages.en.xlf` is working fine. But inside the Container my `LokiTuoResultBundle.forms.en.xlf`will not load.
If I try `php bin/console debug:translation  en LokiTuoResultBundle --domain=LokiTuoResultBundle.forms` It shows clearly my translations

> ---
>
> State      Domain                      Id                           Message Preview (en)
>
> ---
>
> unused    LokiTuoResultBundle.forms   form.resultfile.comment      Comment (e.g. who simmed)
>     unused    LokiTuoResultBundle.forms   form.resultfile.resultfile   Resultfile
>     unused    LokiTuoResultBundle.forms   Submit                       Submit
>     unused    LokiTuoResultBundle.forms   form.player.playername       Playername
>     unused    LokiTuoResultBundle.forms   form.player.guild            Guild
>     unused    LokiTuoResultBundle.forms   form.mission.name            Missionname (with BGE)
>     unused    LokiTuoResultBundle.forms   form.mission.type            Missiontype
>
> ---

When I dump `var_dump(array_keys($this->getContainer()->get('translator')->getCatalogue('en')->all()))` It only shows 4 keys

> array(4) {
>    [0]=>
>    string(10) "validators"
>    [1]=>
>    string(8) "security"
>    [2]=>
>    string(8) "messages"
>    [3]=>
>    string(13) "FOSUserBundle"
>   }

If I use it in my Controller or Command, it wont load my custom Domain.
Is there anything that I need to do, so it will load my custom domain?
Any hints on what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seemed to be The naming of the domain. In my case it hat a `.` in the name. Which caused trouble while loading. Once I removed the dot, everything worked fine.